# How can I remove an issue for a completed sprint in Greenhopper/JIRA?

Tags: jira, jira-agile, greenhopper

How can I remove an issue for a completed sprint in Greenhopper/JIRA?

Comment: See https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Removing+an+Issue+from+a+Sprint However it does not answer your question about removing an issue from the completed sprint.

Comment: Good question, but better asked at https://answers.atlassian.com/

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with Bulk Edit.

Just make search search which finds the only needed issue, and then during bulk edit change sprint. You have to put Sprint ID, not Sprint name. It will be integer number. This number can be found if you make search by Sprint in advanced mode (number will automatically replace Sprint name after putting it in search string).

Answer (score 0):

I created the feature request - https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-9786